# IdentityServer 4 using IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, identityserver4

I'm trying to work with IdentityServer 4.
For now I'm using this link https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples as example.

My problem is that using 
http://localhost:22530/
IdentityServer loading and works, but using it as hosted website on my IIS under http://identity.test.dev it is not loading.

I already tried to run code from this example https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/dev/Mvc/src/IdSvrHost and it doesn't work.

How can I start IdentityServer under IIS via http://identity.test.dev?

Comment: your http://identity.test.dev wouldnt load at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like I solved my problem.

In example when there is not all folders and files are marked to copy during publishing. This is why I add them, see code below:

project.json

```
"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "wwwroot",
    "UI",
    "damienbodserver.pfx",
    "web.config"
  ]}
```